# jQuery - find 1st element with a specific class from above, but not before another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<li class="divider">
  <div>
    ...(maybe more divs)...      
      <div class="content">
         ...(maybe more divs)...
         <a href="#" class="link">LINK</a>

...
```

how can I select the .content DIV, from within a jQuery function hooked on the link?
Note that I have multiple lists like this, and in some of them div.content might be missing, so I want to select this div only if it exists in the current block (li.divider).

I tried with `$link.parent().parent().find('content')` but it fails in some cases, because the number of elements between these 2 elements can change...

Comment: Why won't a single `li.divider div.content` work?

Comment: because there are multiple li.divider things on the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they're not nested, you should be able to do this:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.content');
});
```

or

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div.content:first');
});
```

If they are nested, then you may need to do something like this:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li.divider').find('div.content');
});
```

...so that if there's nesting going on, and there's no `div.content` in the current one, you won't end up selecting a more distant `div.content` ancestor.

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 0):

`$link.parent(".content")`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector...

```
var parentContent = $(this).closest("div.content");

if(parentContent.length > 0) {
  alert("DIV was found!");
}
```